# How to render component after inserting its tag as raw html? Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

So i have a `vue` instance with a globally registered component in a legacy project. Since it's legacy, it mainly uses `jsrender` to render html after some ajax requests.

But even if the component is already registered in the vue instance, vue does not render the new component instance after that data fetch, when component gets inserted as raw html `<component-a></component-a>`.

How do I make vue render this?

I need this to work to be able to gradually inject VueJS into the legacy project

**Further explanation:**

I have this html blocks (`jsrender` templates) like below on the page from the initial page request

```
<script id="some-name-tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
        {{ if var1 == 0 }}
        <div> {{ variable }} etc...</div>
        {{/if}}
        <my-vue-component></my-vue-component> // I need this to get rendered as a component
</script>
```

They get rendered by `jsrender` library when some data come from the backend and in JS some render methods of `jsrender` got called along with the data, so I get something like this:

```
<div> x etc...</div>
<my-vue-component></my-vue-component>
```

But the component (`<my-vue-component></my-vue-component>`) gets inserted just as raw html, though it's inside of the `#app` element on which `vuejs` instance
is mounted, but it gets inserted after the vue instance is already initialized, so `Vue` does not render this component

So I need to force `Vue` to scan the page html again as on `mount()` to render this component. Or I will have to migrate all the templates and data from `jsrender` lib to `Vue` in once and it's a lot of work

Comment: Consider explaining your case further. What exactly do you receive as html? How is it related to jsrender?

Comment: @EstusFlask I've tried, is it clear enough?

Comment: "But the component (<my-vue-component></my-vue-component>) gets inserted just as raw html" - it shouldn't, as long as you have MyVueComponent registered and <my-vue-component> is inside #app at the moment when the app is initialized . It's unclear how exactly jsrender is used, is it on server or client side. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem

Comment: @EstusFlask MyVueComponent is registered globally, but <my-vue-component> will be inside the #app after the app is already initialized, so it won't be rendered by Vue. jsrender is on the client side and it basically just renders a jsrender template and the result gets appended by JQuery as plain html

Comment: This is probably XY problem. Don't initialize the app until you have everything ready for it to work.

Comment: @EstusFlask that is not an option, because that legacy app is already an SPA in some sort. It renders new html (where I want to inject Vue components) not once or twice on page load but on almost every request

Comment: Which request? There's not enough info for the problem. Basically, if html is updated asynchronously, you need to notify vue app about it. And it should be in some container, this is not covered in the question either

Comment: @EstusFlask ajax request, like i've mentioned above in the post. How do you notify Vue about new instances of components after async html updates? That is not very specific. What container?

Comment: What he meant is that you should encapsulate the ajax-fetching and rendering logic into a container component. And that alone will solve part of the "notifying the vue app" problem. The rest is to know how/when to trigger the container to start the ajax-fetching.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you need to render some Vue components after ajax calls and it seems they are out of Vue scope. There are 3 solutions for working with dynamic components, third one may be a solution for your case becuase it works out of Vue.

1. [`v-html`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#raw-html) directive, it's prebuilt feature that you can render HTML string content under an dom element.

```html
<div v-html="htmlStringConent" />
```

2. [Dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-elements.html#component), it's prebuilt component of Vue that accepts one tag name or a selector of a registered component to render it.

```html
<component :is="href ? 'a' : 'registeredComp'"></component>
```

3. [Web component](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components), this is a feature of modern browsers for creating reusable custom elements — with their functionality encapsulated away from the rest of your code. Simply you should [define your Vue compoents](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#building-custom-elements-with-vue) in a way browser could render it like a native dom element. then it works in `jsrenderer` scope automatically.

```js
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'

const MyVueElement = defineCustomElement({
  // normal Vue component options here
  props: {},
  emits: {},
  template: `...`,

  // defineCustomElement only: CSS to be injected into shadow root
  styles: [`/* inlined css */`]
})

// Register the custom element.
// After registration, all `<component-a>` tags
// on the page will be upgraded.
customElements.define('component-a', MyVueElement)
```

then you can use your custom element anywhere the document tree

```html
<component-a></component-a>
```

Hope it will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: I don't think it's going to work, I think this will be rendered as plain html just like the actual component, because the problem is not in the component (its registered from the beginning), but in inserting the component as plain html

Comment: I think the problem is jsrenderer is out of Vue scope that's why Vue can't render the registered component. you should use web-component feature that I explained in the answer.

Comment: I assume that I can't use vue components inside a web component? If I can it sounds like a solution, I need to use some Vue UI library components

Comment: I did not understand your point, you will have same problem if you use Vue library. 
generally in your case,  you should register any component to browser before using it, most of Vue libraries doesn't do it usually.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it right, essentially, you are trying to either render a component whose template is not known **statically**, or a component whose definition is not known **statically**. In other words, you want the template, or the component itself to be the "data" so that it can be fetched remotely/constructed dynamically at runtime.

This is achievable using [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) (the `<component>` tag). The magic is the second bullet point in the document:

> the value passed to :is can contain either:
>
> - the name string of a registered component, OR
> - the **actual imported component object**

Except that you will not import the component, you just **create it on the fly**. Vue component, surprising to most of people, is actually pretty simple - it is just a plain js object (in other words, the component definition is merely a spec).

In your case, one way of doing it is to define a `DynamicComponent` to accept remote template as a string property (let's call it `layout`), and this component can then create an anonymous component on the fly based on the given layout.

In the below example, two existing components are registered globally: `DynamicComponent` and `MyComponent`. The app is not rendering `MyComponent` at the moment. You can type your jsrender-rendered layout as string into the text area, say

```
<my-component msg="hello world">
    <button>I can even accept slot</button>
</my-component>
```

and click the button **Render It**

```js
const App = {
  template: `
    <div style="display: flex; flex-flow: column">
      <h1>App</h1>
      <textarea v-model="text"/>
      <button @click="renderIt"> Render It </button>
      <dynamic-component :layout="layout" />
    </div>`,

  data() {
    return { title: "App", text: "", layout: "" };
  },
  
  methods: {
    renderIt() {
      this.layout = this.text;
    }
  }
}

const MyComponent = {
  props: ["msg"],

  template: `
   <h1>Hello from the MyComponent.vue</h1>
   <div>{{ msg }}</div>
   <slot></slot>
  `,
};


const DynamicComponent = {
  props: ["layout"],

  template: `<component :is="definition" v-if="!!layout" />`,

  computed: {
   definition() {
     return { template: this.layout };
   },
  }
};

const app = Vue.createApp(App);
app.component("my-component", MyComponent);
app.component("dynamic-component", DynamicComponent);
app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Obviously you still might have refactor your code a little bit, e.g. you probably need to figure out a way to know when jsrender has completed its part of the job. Even if there might not be a way to directly ask jsrender to render into a string, you can always just grab the innerHTML/outterHTML and forward it to the DynamicComponent.

Alternatively, **Vue 3 root app can be mounted with dom template**. E.g. it can take the DOM subtree rooted at the designated mounting point as template. This actually feels more ideal for your case, but might involve a bigger refactoring as you will break your entire application into multiple Vue apps so that you can imperatively mount a new Vue app instance when needed.

Comment: That is unfortunately not for my case, cause appending jsrender's html is not the only thing that changes the DOM, in JS also elements attributes and content gets changed, so if that change is not going to be mirrored in the template, Vue will overwrite that once some reactive data of that element is going to change. The only two solutions I see for now is 1. to make my own virtual tree on page load and through mutation observer make any DOM change mirrored in that virtual tree. 2. is to mount separate instances of Vue with mutation observer when it founds any registered component tag in DOM

Comment: The <component :is="definition"/> will be reactive to the definition by the way. Meaning you can jsrender/use whatever mechanism to continuously change the dom and the vue component will re-render accordingly. But you cannot change the dom from both ends and expect them to just work. This sounds like a design problem, and you probably shouldn't consider using VueJS in this case.

Comment: Nice in-depth explaination, thanks. I am using this solution to transform WYSIWYG markup to my components before rendering them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dynamic components in conjunction with the built-in is attribute as a template. This will let vue render raw html along with rendering vue components.

```html
<component :is="{ template: `${html}` }" />
```

then in your computed, return whatever html block you want that has the globally mounted vue component:

```js
computed: {
  html() {
    return `<div> x etc...</div><my-vue-component></my-vue-component>`
  }
}
```

using this method you will need to import:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler'
```

This gives you the ability to use runtime template compilation in your app.